# SQL script isn't executed during launching of mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm very new at docker and docker-composer. I'm trying to make a **mysql container** which will  be used by a php-apache container.
I have a SQL script which create a database and insert values.

I want my mysql container to execute this **SQL script** at his launching, so the app will be able to make queries on it. here's my docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./bdd.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/bdd.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webreathe
  app:
    image: toto:latest
    container_name: toto
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/webreathe
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql

volumes:
  db-volume:
```

I launch it with `docker-compose up -d`

and I want to see if my database was created so I execute inside of the mysql container :
`mysql -u root -p test -e "show databases;"`
but the result is :

```
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

So I wonder if the bdd.sql file was in the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory
and yes it is : `ls docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` => bdd.sql

Do you know why it doesn't execute the script ?

Comment: Did the `db-volume` already exist before you added the `environment:` setting and the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` script?

Comment: How can I Know it ?

Comment: yes it was that, thanks a lot !